# How to create file upload functionality and show error message (Not accept this type of file ---successfully upload the file) in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

This is my view page form HTML code:

**welcome_message.php**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="file" name="profile_name" > 
</div>
```

**Welcome.php**

```
 public function do_upload() {
     $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
     $config['allowed_types'] = 'doc|xml|docx|PDF|DOC|XML|DOCX|xls|xlsx';
     $config['max_size'] = 100;
     $config['max_width'] = 1024;
     $config['max_height'] = 768;

     $this - > load - > library('Welcome', $config);

     if (!$this - > Welcome - > do_upload('profile_name')) {
         $error = array('error' => $this - > upload - > display_errors());

         $this - > load - > view('welcome_message', $error);
     } else {
         $data = array(
             'upload_data' => $this - > upload - > data()
         );

         $this - > load - > view('upload_success', $data);
         //echo "Your file was successfully uploaded!";
     }
 }
```

**This is success function code: upload_success.php**

```
<body>

    <h3>Your file was successfully uploaded!</h3>

    <ul>
        <?php foreach ($upload_data as $item => $value):?>
        <li><?php echo $item;?>: <?php echo $value;?></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>

    <p><?php echo anchor('upload', 'Upload Another File!'); ?></p>

</body>
```

Comment: this is my code not showing error message and not upload file kindly any one help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->load->library('Welcome', $config);
$this->upload->initialize($config);
```

Check if this help you, initialize upload config after loading library.